# <b-form-input> bind value does not update on the second time

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am currently implementing a component that update parent's **year[]** array when **year to / year[1]** value is lower than **year from / year[0]** with `<b-input>` (Bootstrap Vue Library).

The **year to** stop updating after the second time.

Code example are as below.

Code equivalent in jsfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/darkyduckduck/ybdx6043/58/).

Parent.vue

```html
<template>
  <child :year="year" @update="update">
</template>

<script>
// Import child component here

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  data: () => ({
    year: [100, null],
  }),
  methods: {
    update(newYear) {
      this.year = newYear;
    },
  },
</script>
```

Child.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    From <b-input :value="year[0]" />
    To <b-input :value="year[1]" @change="update" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  props: {
    year: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(yearToVal) {
      const [yearFrom] = this.year;
      let newYear = [...this.year];
      
      if (yearToVal < yearFrom) {
        /* Both of this update end up the same */
        // newYear[1] = yearFrom;
        this.$set(newYear, 1 , yearFrom);
      }
      this.$emit('update', newYear);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I had used Vue Dev Tools to check and the child is emitting data correctly to the parent.

The issue happen on the `vModalValue` and `localValue` of the `<b-input>` are not updating on the second time.

What am I doing wrongly or is it a Bootstrap Vue library problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Hiws's answer](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/6711#issuecomment-885610900) indicate that the this problem does not only happen on `<b-form-input>` but ordinary `<input>` with Vue as well.

This happen due to Vue not able to react to changes since the update is happening on child, hence when **year to** is lower than **year from**, parent will not detect any changes on the second time as the array pass to Parent.vue will always be [100,100].

The solution will be using watcher on Parent.vue's array to detect the changes, hence both eg: `[100, 1] -> [100,100]` are both reflected on Parent.vue and most importantly, force the component to re-render.

Without force re-rendering, `[100,1] or [100,2]...` will always be treated as `[100,100]`, the same value, and Vue will not react or even update to them.

[Jsfiddle equivalent solution can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/darkyduckduck/nazgfpjv/27/)

Code sample below:

Parent.vue

```html
<template>
  <child :year="year" @update="update">
</template>

<script>
// Import child component here

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  data: () => ({
    year: [100, null],
    yearKey: 0,
  }),
  watch: {
    year: {
      handler(val) {
        if (val[1] < val[0]) {
          let newYear = [...val]; 
          newYear[1] = val[0];
          this.year = newYear;
          // key update reference: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/
          this.yearKey += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(newYear) {
      this.year = newYear;
    },
  },
</script>
```

Child.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    From <b-input :value="year[0]" />
    To <b-input :value="year[1]" @change="update" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  props: {
    year: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(yearToVal) {
      const [yearFrom] = this.year;
      let newYear = [...this.year];
      newYear[1] = yearToVal;

      this.$emit('update', newYear);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: After a few read, I think something is not right. Can anybody help with this?